# Добавить click к body

Tags: javascript, jquery

По неопытности не получается реализовать задачу. Что нужно дописать к данному коду, чтобы возврат к исходному состоянию (Меню) можно было реализовать, как через клик по .openclosebtn, так и через клик по body?

```js
$('.openclosebtn').click(function() {
  if (!$(this).data('status')) {
    $(this).html('Close');
    $(this).data('status', true);
  } else {
    $(this).html('Меню');
    $(this).data('status', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <span class="openclosebtn">Меню</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос, состоянию чего?

Клик на body в jquery будет так $('body').on('click', function () {}); только он будет, скорей всего перекрыт другими элементами...

Чего именно вы добиваетесь?

Comment: нужно, что бы менюшка исчезала при клике куда угодно. Это как я понял...

Comment: Исходное состояние это слово — "Меню". Не исчезала куда угодно, просто чтобы менялось на слово "Close".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
// Бинд кнопки
$('.togglebtn').click(() => {
  if (checkIsOpened()) {
    closeMenu()
  } else {
    openMenu()
  }
})

// Бинд документа
$(document).click(event => {
  // Здесь мы проверяем, что мы кликнули не по кнопке открытия меню 
  // или её внутренностям
  if (!$(event.target).is('.togglebtn, .togglebtn *')) {
    closeMenu()
  }
})

// Возврващает состояние меню
function checkIsOpened() {
  return !!$('.togglebtn').data('opened')
}

// Закрывает меню
function closeMenu() {
  $('.togglebtn').data('opened', false)
  $('#menustate').text('Закрыто')
}

// Открывает меню
function openMenu() {
  $('.togglebtn').data('opened', true)
  $('#menustate').text('Открыто')
}
```

```css
.togglebtn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  background: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="togglebtn">
  Меню: <span id="menustate">Закрыто</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Всё подробно и понятно. Спасибки!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var btn = $('.openclosebtn');

btn.click(function() {
  if (!btn.data('status')) {
    btn.html('Close');
    btn.data('status', true);
  } else {
    btn.html('Меню');
    btn.data('status', false);
  }
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  if (!btn.is(e.target) && // если кнопка - не цель клика
    btn.has(e.target).length === 0 && // и кнопка не содержит в себе цель клика
    btn.data('status')) { // и status = true
    btn.html('Меню');
    btn.data('status', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <span class="openclosebtn">Меню</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Понятно и доходчиво. Спасибки!

Answer (score 0):

Есть нечто подобное на чистом JS

```
window.onclick = function(event){
    if(!event.target.matches('.search-category__btn')){
        categoryDropdown.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

.search-category__btn можно заменить на .openclosebtn ну и дальше...

Comment: На чистом js..рад, что показали именно на нём, очень интересно. Спасибки!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(() => {
  let menuIsOpen = false;
  const $body = $('body'),
    $menu = $('.menu'),
    $menuButton = $menu.find('.openclosebtn');
    
    $menuButton.on('click', toggleMenu);
    
    function toggleMenu() {
      if(!menuIsOpen) menuShow();
      else menuHide();
    }
    
    function menuShow() {
      $menuButton.html('Close');
      $menu.addClass('show');
      $body.on('click', menuHideOnBodyClick); // Когда меню открыто, вешаем обработчик клика по body
      menuIsOpen = true;
    }
    
    function menuHide() {
      $menuButton.html('Меню');
      $menu.removeClass('show');
      $body.off('click', menuHideOnBodyClick); // Когда меню закрыто, отключаем обработчик клика по body
      menuIsOpen = false;
    }
    
    function menuHideOnBodyClick( e ) {
      const $elem = $(e.target);
      /*
      * Проверяем является ли то на что мы кликнули нашим меню
      * или чем-то дочерним для него,
      * если нет, то закрываем меню
      */
      if(!$elem.closest('.menu').length) menuHide();
    }
});
```

```css
body { height: 500px; }
.menu { width: 140px; }
.menu_content { display: none; }
.menu.show .menu_content { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="menu">
    <span class="openclosebtn">Меню</span>
    <div class="menu_content">
      <ul>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: нужно больше кода!

Comment: @Cheg, Зато какая наглядность! xDD

Comment: Да-а, чётко здесь всё, спасибо большое!