# Прятать блок при клике другом месте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте. Есть 2 блока: `#contacts-view` и `.yes-open-phone`. 
если кликнуть на блок `#contacts-view` - появляется блок `.yes-open-phone`, если еще раз кликнуть на `#contacts-view` - блок .`yes-open-phone` пропадает.

Вопрос: Как сделать чтобы блок `.yes-open-phone` так же пропадал при клике в любом другом месте страницы?

мой код:

```
$("#contacts-view").click(function() {
    if ($(".yes-open-phone").css('display') == 'none') {
        $(".yes-open-phone").animate({height: 'show'}, 300);
        $(".contacts-tab").css({"border":"1px solid #bd2c3c"});
        $(".open-phone").css({"background":"url('/style/img/close-phone-color.png') no-repeat"});
    }else{
        $(".yes-open-phone").animate({height: 'hide'}, 300);
        $(".contacts-tab").css({"border":"1px solid #fff"});
        $(".open-phone").css({"background":"url('/style/img/open-phone.png') no-repeat"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Закрытие div при клике вне его](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433249/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-div-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be)

Comment: Или [Как в javascript “закрывать” div при клике вне этого дива?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/140922/)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Добавить click к body](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/718023/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-click-%d0%ba-body)

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(function(){

$('#contacts-view').click(function(e){
    $('.yes-open-phone').toggle();
    return false;
});

$('body').click(function(e){
    if(!$('.yes-open-phone').is(e.target)){
        $('.yes-open-phone').hide();
    }
    return true;
});
});
```

```css
body{
   width:100%;height:1000px;
}
.yes-open-phone{
   display: inline-block;
   padding:10px;
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<button type=button id="contacts-view">Открывалка</button>
<div class="yes-open-phone">
    Кликни мимо
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: А вы сами хоть пробовали ваш код применить?

Comment: @Cheg Оформил в виде демки, чтобы развеять ваш скепсис.

Comment: А теперь добавьте код кнопки (#contacts-view), которая открывает и скрывает .yes-open-phone, и увидите, что код ваш не работает.

Comment: Добавил кнопку и обработчик с return false. Всё работает.